# How to parse Nested JSON - Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

How to parse this JSON response without creating a model class?

```
{"data":[{"Status":"0"}]}
```

I did try by fetching it as `jsonResponse['data']['Status']`, but got an error stating that  **Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'**, but if i just try by `jsonResponse['data']` I'm getting the result as `[{Status: 0}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below
`[{"Status":"0"}]` is a `List` 
You can use  `jsonResponse["data"][0]["Status"]` 
code snippet

```
String jsonString = '''
    {"data":[{"Status":"0"}]}
    ''';

var jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
print(jsonResponse["data"][0]["Status"]);
```

output

```
I/flutter ( 6912): 0
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(       
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,        
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    String jsonString = '''
    {"data":[{"Status":"0"}]}
    ''';

    var jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    print(jsonResponse["data"][0]["Status"]);

    setState(() {     
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(        
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(        
        child: Column(          
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```